# How to remove the need of txt extension with a final optional trailing slash in url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

How to remove the need of txt extension of txt files and add a final optional trailing slash in url using htaccess regex in php

my code is

```
   #turn on url rewriting 
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .txt extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/?)$ $1.txt
```

But it throws 500 Server error.What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts/htaccess file in your question. Please do let us know your sample url which you are hitting and getting an error, thank you.

Comment: https://pozecon.com/view/file/code-demo/

Comment: and the real txt file is
https://pozecon.com/view/file/code-demo.txt

Comment: Could you please try changing this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.txt -f` TO `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\.txt -f` once and see if that helps you? Not tested it though, let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok..1 minute wait

Comment: now it's throwing 404 error
check this :
https://pozecon.com/view/file/code-demo/

Comment: Could you please do let me know where is your htaccess file exist? And where are your files exist(.txt ones)?

Comment: in root folder  public_html

Comment: Please give complete path here for better understanding its not clear as of now.

Comment: complete path for .htaccess file is :

/home/user/public_html

Comment: and the  complete path of txt file is :

Comment: /home/user/public_html/view/file/code-demo.txt

Comment: I think your rules are ok, try once `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.txt [END]` assuming these are the only rules you have in your htaccess file so END flag will come out of it once a rule is applied. Let me know how it goes? Also make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs

Comment: Here is my complete .htaccess file content  https://pozecon.com/source/file/htaccess

Comment: Could you please do let me know if you have tried my suggested rule in my previous comment?

Comment: yes I have tried.Its showing 404 error

Comment: ok, try setting `RewriteBase /` after line `RewriteEngine on` and try again once?

Comment: Updated,But same 404 error.Please take a look in to my htaccess file content https://pozecon.com/source/file/htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following, please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Fair warning I haven't tested it as of now.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.txt [L]
```

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comments adding following solution.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.txt [L]
```

Comment: @theObserver, When I checked in my local, htaccess in `/var/www/html` and rules `RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.txt [L]` it worked for me with OR without `/` when I hit `curl -IL "http://localhost:80/view/file/code-demo/"` it gives `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` because file is present there, let me know.

Comment: no it's not working..May be some problems in my server??? Let me check the whole thing.. Thanks for your support..See you soon.

Comment: There was a problem with my code editor .Codes are mis encoded .. I Noticed the problem finally and fixed it.Thank you.

Comment: @theObserver, ohh man, I spend so much time on that :) :) Happy that it solved for you, very happy cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Ofcourse..I appreciate your good work..and staying longer with this chat. Thanks..

Comment: @theObserver, you could also up-vote my answer too for encouraging on SO cheers :)